# jquery cookie close button

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cookies

I've done a lot of searching on google and here about using cookies to store browser location and to be able to return to that location if a page is refreshed, returned too, etc. but I'm not sure how to ask the right question to get what I would like to have done.

To be upfront I'm more of a designer than a developer. However I do have basic skills when it comes to jQuery. With that said i'm looking for a way to close a Wordpress post loaded via ajax that will take the user back to the page position where they were when they clicked to open the post.

I have several post on one page and I want them to be able to return to that position once they close they close a post they just read. I hope that make sense?

So pretty much a close button that returns user to previous page position once finished.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the need of cookie here..??

Comment: Hi Mohammad i've read about the jQuery cookie plugin being used to store the page location when clicked. I understand how to set the cookie when a link is clicked. Just not sure how to get back to the point where the cookie was set.

Comment: Hi Mohammad,
I just revised my question.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:history.back(-1);">Go back</a>
```

this will be take back the prviously position. Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Hi @netdjw. Thanks for the info but I'm aware of this method. My problem is that when more than one comment is submitted on the page then the browser history can become an unknown if person (a) submits one comment and person (b) submits two comments. I don't want person (b) to hit the close button and it only takes them back one page when in fact they need to go back two pages. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how your wordpress posts are rendered in HTML, the general way of solving something like this is to pass in the x,y coordinates to your close button (when the user clicks on the link to read the post) and when the user clicks on the close button you can use the scroll function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scroll) to scroll to a specific point in the browser.

Comment: Hi Mahesh,
Would you be willing to post an example of the above? So if user clicks <a href="post_url_1"> then is taken to another page. When they close post_url_1 they will be taken back to the previous page where they clicked?
Thanks

Comment: Is the source page under by control? i.e. the page where the user clicks to go to the actual post. Can you change the source/add more scripting to it?

Comment: So basically you need to add onload logic on the landing page which displays the links, to scroll down to a specific set of x,y coordinates, IF they are passed in the request as a query parameter. Idea is, when the user clicks on a post to read it, you dynamically compute the x,y coordinates and then pass it to the post. The post will stick that in the close function, and the close function will pass it back to the landing page. The landing page will look at the request and pull the x,y coordinates and scroll down appropriately.